# Java android layout inside Two layouts

Tags: java, android

I have a question can I put e.g LinearLayot inside two LinearLayots  ? I read about `Coordinator layot` but I think that I can use this.

Comment: Yes of-course you can put

Comment: better to go for constrainlayout

Comment: @Piyush could you help me ? I try do this , but I don't know how

Comment: @Shreyansh could you show me how it works ?

Comment: Its a flat layout where you don't need to have nested layouts. You can refer this link for a better understanding https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Comment: @Shreyansh I try do this but I can't

Comment: You should mention what you want to achieve as a final UI

Comment: @Shreyansh I have e.g two linear layouts and I want to craeate a 3rd linearlayout and put inide 1st and 2nd linear layot. A 3rd linear layout should be half on 1rs layot and half in 2nd layout

Comment: You can't.Actually what you want to achieve by doing this? Screenshot may clear an idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144340/discussion-between-krzysztof-pokrywka-and-shreyansh).

Comment: @Shreyansh I want to create this view  :  http://pokazywarka.pl/iilkai/

Answer (score 0):

YES. you can do this.but pay attention:
"if you make changes in one of them, doesn't happened in others because in java, compiler makes an object for your layout that is not same the object created for it in other layouts".

hope helps you.

Comment: But how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Simply embed them within each other in the XML file associated with the layout.